# RSpec specify header on get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, http-headers

I'm doing the following get request on RSpec:

```
get "api/posts/#{@post.id}?api_key=#{Settings.api_key.android}&device_token=#{@device.token}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}"
```

I need to specify the header.

on Postman my header looks something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1qmm9aqwu3xm4i/Screenshot%202015-11-30%2014.41.10.png?dl=0

How would I add my header to my get request on RSpec?

I've tried this:

```
get "api/posts/#{@post.id}?api_key=#{Settings.api_key.android}&device_token=#{@device.token}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", nil, {'ACCEPT' => 'application/vdn.foo.v10'}
```

Without any success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer in [Set header in RSpec 3 request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815741/set-header-in-rspec-3-request). You can access the request using the `request` variable as well and manipulate the headers directly on there.