# Integration Testing a rails API using devise_token_auth for authenticaton and cancancan for authorization using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rails-api, cancancan

I have a rails-api application that I'm testing using Rspec. The Application uses [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem for authentication and [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem for authorization.

devise_token_auth requires that the client include these authentication headers in every request:
`access-token`, `client`, `expiry`, `uid`. These headers are available in a response after successful authentication using `email` and `password`.

I have decided to use a solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815741/set-header-in-rspec-3-request/25847940#25847940) to set these headers during testing.

In `ability.rb` I have this:

```
## models/ability.rb

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
   if user.role? :registered
     can :create, Post, user_id: user.id
     can :update, Post, user_id: user.id
     can :destroy, Post, user_id: user.id
     can :read, Post
   end
  end
end
```

`posts#show` action in `PostsController` looks like this:

```
## controllers/posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    render json: @post
  end
end
```

I have rescued `CanCan::AccessDenied` error to render a json message and a status of `403` `forbidden` in `ApplicationController`

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  render json: {"message" => "unauthorized"}.to_json, :status => 403
end
```

I have this in `spec/support/session_helper.rb`

```
module SessionHelper
 def retrieve_access_headers

 ##I have a user with these credentials and has a "registered" role. in the the test db.

   post "/auth/sign_in", params: {:email => "registered_user@gmail.com", :password => "g00dP@ssword"}, headers: {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json"}

##These two pass
expect(response.response_code).to eq 200
expect(response.body).to match(/"email": "registered_user@gmail.com"/)

     access_headers = {"access-token" => response.headers["access-token"],
     "client" => response.headers["client"],
     "expiry" => response.headers["expiry"],
     "uid" => response.headers["uid"],
     "token-type" => response.headers["token-type"],
     'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json"
   }

  return access_headers
 end
```

end

I have this in `spec/support/requests_helper.rb`

```
module RequestsHelper
  def get_with_token(path, params={}, headers={})
   headers.merge!(retrieve_access_headers)
   get path, params: params, headers: headers

   #### this outputs the expected headers on a json string and they seem fine ####
   puts "headers: "+headers.to_json
  end
end
```

I have included the two helpers in `rails_helper.rb` as shown below:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include SessionHelper, type: :request
   config.include RequestsHelper, type: :request
end
```

Finally I have a request spec in `spec/request/posts/show_spec.rb`

```
require 'rspec/its'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'GET /posts/:id', :type => :request do

    let(:post) {create(:post)}
    let(:id) {post.id}
    let(:request_url) {"/posts/#{id}"}

  context 'with a registered user' do
   it 'has a status code of 200' do
     get_with_token request_url
     expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
   end
  end
end
```

I expect this to pass but it fails with message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
   expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 403
```

The application works as expected on a browser.

What I'm a doing wrong?

Comment: There are two things that stand out: a) you are not adding `before_filter :authenticate_user!`(Rails 3) or `before_action :authenticate_user!` to your controller (unless you have added it directly to the `ApplicationController`class). b) if you are using `load_and_authorize_resource` you should not initialize `@post` in your controller action (you are effectively by-passing the cancancan framework this way)

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Thank you for that observation, i've made the edits in my application and the original question as well, but the spec is still failing as before.

Comment: Next thing: are you linking the user and the post in your factory? In other words, does `create(:post)` set the correct user_id in the post object? Another thing worth checking is to dump the `current_user` to the console in the `show` method to see if the error is whether in authenticating the user or in authorizing the resource...

Comment: @MarcoSandrini This is the first spec i'm writing for the application, i wanted to move a step at a time to avoid being overwhelmed, I have not linked the user yet since the `ability` does not require the `user` be linked to a `post` to `read` any `post`. I will link them when i start writing the spec for `create`, `update` and `destroy` which require that the user performing those actions be the owner of the resource.

Comment: You are right, I read the ability file to quickly.... I just now noticed that you invoke get like `get path, params: params, headers: headers`, while I think it should be like `get path, params, headers`....

Comment: @MarcoSandrini I'm on rails 5.0 beta, I think that's the new way of doing it, I got a deprecation warning when I did it the way you propose:     `DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest HTTP request methods will accept only
the following keyword arguments in future Rails versions:
params, headers, env, xhr

Examples:

get '/profile',
  params: { id: 1 },
  headers: { 'X-Extra-Header' => '123' },
  env: { 'action_dispatch.custom' => 'custom' },
  xhr: true
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100519/discussion-between-marco-sandrini-and-optimus-pette).