# Set headers before each request in RSpec request spec

Tags: rspec-rails

How do I set headers within `before each` like below?

```
RSpec.describe "Users API", type: :request do
  before :each do
    host! "example.org"
    // set a header for all requests here ??
  end
end
```

Possible duplicate: [How to set request headers in rspec request spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654465/how-to-set-request-headers-in-rspec-request-spec)

But above didn't answer my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set header in RSpec 3 request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815741/set-header-in-rspec-3-request)

Answer (score -1):

Found one solution. Include the `Rack::Test::Methods` module.
I don't know why request specs doesn't provide this feature.

```
RSpec.describe "Users API", type: :request do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  before :each do
    host! "example.org"
    // now we can do
    header 'Authorization', "Bearer #{some_token}"
  end
end
```

Comment: including Rack::Test::Methods breaks the whole Request Spec flow, result of get|post|put... method will not be assigned to the response variable anymore. Do not do it in request specs.

Comment: @januszm You are right. Perhaps best thing is to set the header manually for each request rather than looking for a shortcut method.