# RSpec/rails not setting request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

## Problem

I'm setting up tests, using *RSpec*, for an api, made with *rails*. In one of the tests, I'm trying to add some authentication headers, however it appears the headers won't add up to my request. How can I properly pass those headers?

I need to pass 3 headers (*client*, *access-token* and *uid*) so the system recognizes the user as logged. If I don't pass, I get the system not logged [error message](https://imgur.com/a/JKBSm73)

If I manually try accessing the same endpoint, the one I'm making the test for, on *postman* and simply pass the headers, [it works](https://imgur.com/a/9F6BelC)

## Code

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::Profiles::CreditCardsController, type: :api do
  describe 'POST /api/v1/profiles/credit_cards' do
    let!(:profiles) {FactoryGirl.create_list(:profile, 1)}
    it 'Usuário cadastrando cartão no sistema' do
      number = Faker::Stripe.valid_card
      params = {
          :number => number,
          :expiration_date => Faker::Stripe.year + '/' + Faker::Stripe.month,
          :brand => 'Visa',
          :proper_name => Faker::Name.name,
          :cvv => Faker::Stripe.ccv,
      }
      headers = auth_headers(profiles[0])
      requisicao = post '/api/v1/profiles/credit_cards', params, headers  
      # byebug
      expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

## Results

During my *byebug* if I access my variable *headers*, which is the one I'm trying to add, I have the right things set:

```
{"access-token"=>"eQV4yjzKU7cfCgD2kLcMPQ", "client"=>"FWJQNb-aRFD6lmYW1MU8Sw", "uid"=>"ericrice@feeney.com"}
```

**Note:** the values above aren't real values, they were generated by *factory girl* library

However, when I access my *request headers* they don't show up:

```
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "X-Request-Id"=>"0ed4657c-507d-4033-bc20-81d452de0d1b", "X-Runtime"=>"0.004898", "Date"=>"Wed, 16 Jan 2019 16:43:03 GMT", "X-Rack-Cache"=>"pass", "Vary"=>"Origin", "Content-Length"=>"59"}
```

## Updates

### First update

I tried switching from *type :api* to *type :request*. The *type :api* was including *Rack::Test::Methods*, which was messing up my response variable, as pointed by @januszm in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848444/10480047). However, that didn't seem to have any effect with my situation, at first. But them I insisted on testing and realized that did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from type *:api* to type *:request* gave me access to the *request* and *response* variables, which, before, I had to created variables myself to try access them.

When using *type :api*, I had access to *last_response* instead of *response*, because my *type :api* was including *Rack::Test::Methods*, which was messing up those variables (response and request), as according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848444/10480047).

When I switched to *type :request*, and was no longer importing *Rack::Test::Methods*, I was able to access *request* variable and saw that the desired headers were correctly added.